# how to perform search service using async task on changing text input

Tags: android, android-asynctask

I am trying to perform search service using Async task on changing text input in edit text as following:

```
et_search.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {

            public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {

               //my asyncTask

                }
            }

            public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {
            }

            public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {
            }
        });
```

but I want to stop the current running async to perform new one on changing text

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can **cancel** running **aynctask** where you want
first initialize your aynctask class to **globally**

```
private YourAsyncTask mTask;
```

and in your editetxt first check if your async class is not null than cancel previously class and execute again

```
et_search.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {

        public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {

           //my asyncTask
             if(mtask != null){
                 mTask.cancel(true);
              }
             mTask = new YourAsyncTask().execute(et_search.getText().toString());
            }
        }

        public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {
        }

        public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {
        }
    });
```

You can call async class in **onTextChanged()** method